# How to initialize Mediawiki shared database tables?

Tags: mediawiki

I am trying to initialize a new Mediawiki family. I use [this guide](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Shared_database), of course. In the [Upgrading](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Shared_database#Upgrading) section of the guide, it is mentioned:

> As of MediaWiki 1.21, when upgrading MediaWiki from the web installer, $wgSharedTables must be temporarily cleared during upgrade. Otherwise, the shared tables are not touched at all (neither tables with `$wgSharedPrefix`, nor those with `$wgDBprefix`), which may lead to a failed upgrade.

It is right, because using this setting:

```php
$wgSharedDB = 'wiki_shared';
$wgSharedTables[] = array('user','user_groups','actor');
$wgSharedPrefix = '';
```

I had no success in setting the db up; no shared tables are created in the wiki_shared db (it remains an empty db).

How should I "clear `$wgSharedTables`" to avoid facing this issue?

Comment: Clear the list by removing the items from it. `$wgSharedTables[] = array();`

Comment: @GolezTrol I tried that. No success.

Answer (score 1):

(Even though this is old, just in case someone will get here...)

First of all, this is how to clear `$wgSharedTables`:

```
$wgSharedTables = [];
```

All the other options just added a new empty array into the array.

Also, This is not the way you set `$wgSharedTables`. You essentially added an array inside the array; however, each table is supposed to be its own item. Either use `array_merge()`:

```php
$wgSharedTables = array_merge( $wgSharedTables, [ user','user_groups','actor' ] );
```

Or set each one separately:

```php
$wgSharedTables[] = 'user';
$wgSharedTables[] = 'user_groups';
$wgSharedTables[] = 'actor';
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.6.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.13/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.1/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.1.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).